# c# winapp add app.config to installer?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer, app-config

Okay I've got my app.config file that is containing my database settings.

All works well on my development machine. But when I install it on a test machine I'm getting a null reference on the following line:

ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConn"].ToString();

Why is this happening? I guess that the app.config file isn't found. But isn't this included when you build the setup?

I'm using a very simple setup project in VS2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file `app.Config` is your source, don't distribute it. When Visual Studio builds your project it copies the file to `{AppName}.exe.config` (in the same folder as `{AppName}.exe` ) and that is the file you need to include in your setup.

Answer (score 3):

Select app.config in solution explorer and in the properties tab choose the copy action:

```
Copy to Output Directory -> Copy always
```

or

```
Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if newer
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to rename the app.config to the name of the exe.

ie. 
 **myprogram.exe** would have an app.config called **myprogram.exe.config**